# Share Progressive web apps testing experiences

Tags: manual-testing

The latest trend in web application is Progressive web apps (shortly known as PWA). Can you share your experiences in testing this?

Comment: This a question and answer site.  Not suitable for just "experience sharing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below are few basic checklist for Progressive web apps Testing used    in the software testing companies:-**

1. Test/verify site is served over HTTPS.
2. Verify all of pages design are responsive on tablets & mobile devices.
3. Ensure the app presents some content even when offline.Load various pages in the PWA with an airplane mode enabled.
4. Verify time to interactive should be  < 10s for first visit on a simulated 3G network i.e. First load should be fast even on 3G.
5. Test site in Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Safari i.e. cross browser testing.
6. Page transitions within the apps should be faster on the network even on 3G.
7. Ensure individual pages are deep linkable via the URLs and that URLs are unique for the purpose of shareability on social media by testing with individual pages can be opened and directly accessed via new browser windows.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link, you will get some ideas

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-progressive-web-applications